# Can't detect gestures on google map

Tags: flutter, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I want to detect user gestures on google map. I am using following code to do that.
But I am not getting any detection.

Can anyone provide some help on why I am not getting any detection.

```
SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                  print(details);
                },
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                  print(details);
                },
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: !model.isLoading,
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: !model.isLoading,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  minMaxZoomPreference:
                      MinMaxZoomPreference(_minZoom, _maxZoom),
                  initialCameraPosition: _currentCameraPosition,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
                    this.mapController = controller;

                    // listen to map events
                    this._listenToEvents();

                  },
                  onCameraMove: (CameraPosition pos) {},
                  onCameraMoveStarted: () {
                    this._cameraMovementStarted = true;
                  },
                  onCameraIdle: () {
                    if (this._cameraMovementStarted) {
                      this._cameraMovementStarted = false;
                      this._mapMovementCompleted();
                    }
                  },
                  gestureRecognizers: Set()
                    ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                        () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
                          ..onUpdate = (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                            print(details);
                          })),
                  markers: Set.of(model.mapMarkers.values),
                  polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(model.polyLines.values),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            MapOverlayPanel(
                model: model,
                moveToCurrentPos: this.moveCameraToCurrentUserPosition),
            _mapLoadingIndicator(),
          ],
        ))
```

Comment: you can try to remove the GestureDetector Widget, it's not needed. if you really need it, then set the HitTestBehavior to translucent

Comment: @ArnaudDelubac thank you for your answer. Then how do you detect the drag? How do I modify the code to detect it?

Comment: can anyone provide some advice on how to detect the gestures?

Comment: What is the code inside the overlay? Are you sure it's not taking the whole map size? If so, then this is the reason why you don't have gestures, the overlay widget is on top of the ggMap in your stack

Comment: Overlay has several buttons. Even without the overlay I am not getting any detection. I assume ..onUpdate = (DragUpdateDetails details)  is correct way to detect?